# ionic 5 cordova fcm with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to implement FCM using firebase which uses Push notification for my application. I had tried many times still not able to read the token from FCM. Where am I going wrong?

**Code and snips.**

[image]

Error response:

if i use *ionic serve* locally the following error and warning shows up

[image]

if i use *ionic cordova run browser* i get this **before logging** into my application

[image]

**after logging**

[image]

*I took a build of the same app and tried remote debugging on it which had the following error*

**Before logging in**

[image]

**after logging in**

[image]

In every instance the error message indicates to install Cordova-fm plugin which i have done.

my package.json

[image]

[image]

I have tried removing android plugin and install it like a new project didnt work, same error.
I have tried to run just firebase and fcm in a blank Ionic project, still the same error.
I have tried to downgrade the version to see if its works, the error didnt change.

I have tried most of the suggestions from online. Nothing is letting me access the FCM token.

PS: This is my first project with ionic and firebase.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text / code / configurations / errors etc. that you can just copy as text into here.

Comment: @JamesZ Thank you...may be next time i wont repeat this!

Comment: some plugin will not work in browser. Try it in real Device.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib yeah already did it. Remote debugging on apk. Still same issue